# How to throw exception to next catch?

Tags: c#, exception

[image]

I want to throw an exception at next catch, (I attached image)

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You'd have to wrap the inner try/catch with the second try/catch.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, they are hard to read for people with older eyes, and impossible to cut and paste.

Comment: Sadly, C# does not support conditional catch blocks, like F# and VB.Net (e.g. in VB.Net, you could easily use `Catch e as AdsException When tried < 5`)

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Without screenshot however it'd be harder to point to the right places in the code. perhaps a color command should be added to markdown syntax to more easily distinguish important words from the rest of the code

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't, and trying to do so suggests that you've got too much logic in your `catch` blocks, or that you should refactor your method to only do *one* thing. If you can't redesign it, you'll have to nest your `try` blocks:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsException)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            throw; // Throws to the *containing* catch block
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
}
```

On the other hand, as of C# 6, there are *exception filters* so you can check a condition before *actually* catching the exception:

```cs
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsException) when (tries < 5)
{
    tries++;
    // etc
}
// This will catch any exception which isn't an AdsException *or* if
// if the condition in the filter isn't met.
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: you've got a point regarding refactoring the method. but perhaps you should consider the suggestion of @l33t too.

Comment: @Rouven: Please note when this answer was written. C# 6 was released in July 2015.

Comment: @JonSkeet, could you edit your answer to add the conditional catch block from C# 6? Just so the accepted answer is complete. Thanks for the contribution btw :)

Comment: @MSoutto: Done, although I don't make a habit of editing answers for newer language versions, otherwise I'd spend my whole life doing nothing else...

Answer (score 50):

`C# 6.0` to the rescue!

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex) when (tried < 5)
{
}
```

Comment: Best answer (for current day and age), thanks so much for posting. :+1:

Comment: Now it's official! I'm better than Jon Skeet :P

Comment: I don't think that this actually answers the core question. 

This is the answer for the question: "How do I try multiple times before catching an exception?"

The core question is, basically: "How do I throw from one catch to another catch in the same sequence?", and the answer is: "You can't, the catches must be nested."

Comment: True. Though, having nested try/try blocks seems like a bad idea in the first place.

Answer (score 16):

One possibility is nesting the try/catch clause:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        /* ... */
    }
    catch(Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsException ex)
    {
        /* specific handling */
        throw;
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    /* common handling */
}
```

there is also another way - using only your general catch statement and checking the exception type yourself:

```
try
{
    /* ... */
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if(ex is Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsException)
    {
        /* specific handling */
    }

    /* common handling */
}
```

Comment: I agree with both options to answer the Op's question most accurately.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by [Honza Brestan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13573349/1336654):

```
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  bool isAdsExc = e is Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsException;

  if (isAdsExc)
  {
    tried++;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }

  if (tried > 5 || !isAdsExc)
  {
    txn.Rollback();
    log.Error(" ...
    ...
  }
}
finally
{
```

It's ugly to have two `try` blocks nested inside each other.

If you need to use properties of the `AdsException`, use an `as` cast instead of `is`.